# Handlebars, JS and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get hold of the data sent by the server from a MongoDB. A regular GET:

```
.get('/test', function(req, res){
  mongo.collection('collection').find({ _id:req.user._id.toString()
    }).toArray( function(err, doc){
        res.render('partials/map', 
          { docs : doc });
      }
    });      
});
```

I.e. sending an array with the documents to the client. Then I want to manipulate the data on the client side so I, in the javascript on the client do:

```
<script>
  var docs = '{{docs}}';
  console.log(typeof(docs));
  console.log(docs);

  var obj = new Object(docs);
  console.log(obj);

  var arr = new Array(docs);
  console.log(arr);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(docs)); 

</script>
```

However, I can't figure out how to actually manipulate it as the above just gives me the following outputs (in the console):

```
string
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
String {"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"}
["[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"]
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

How can I manipulate the data? I know it's an array with three documents but just trying docs[0] gives the first character in [object Object] (i.e. "["). Also, a JSON.parse(docs) just returns error as docs somehow already is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stringify the object on the server and then access it on the client.

```
//server
res.render('partials/map', {docs: JSON.stringify(doc)})

//client
var docs = {docs}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives back: "Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse", or can I handle the quotes somehow on the client?

Comment: Alright, with: console.log(JSON.parse(docs.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))); it works perfectly. Thanks @Josan!

Comment: Sorry you actually don't have to parse it. It should work without JSON.parse. I'll update the answer